# Redux immutable pattern

Tags: redux, react-redux, immutability

I use react with redux.

**Action**:

```
export const updateClicked = (id, section) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.UPDATE_CLICKED,
    id,
    section
  };
};
```

Please advise the best way to immutable update property in nested array:

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  updates: {
    html: {
      id: 'html',
      label: 'HTML',
      count: 0,
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          label: 'Header',
          price: 10,
          bought: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          label: 'Sidebar',
          price: 50,
          bought: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

My action:

```
action = {
  id: 1,
  bought: true
}
```

I want to update `bought` property inside items array. I.e.:

```
const updateClicked= (state, action) => {
    const updateSections = state.updates[action.section].items;
    const updatedItems = updateSections.map(el => {
        if (el.id === action.id && !el.bought) {
          el.bought = true;
        }

        return el;
    });

   //How to update state???
   return {}
};
```

Will be glad if you explain 2 ways to do this:

1. With es6 spread operator
2. With some library (like immutability-helper)

Thanks!

Comment: I know that this doesn't answer your question. I will get to that later :-) But before I get to that I would like to advise you to normalize the state of your store. Because if you kept the state of the store normalized, it would be a lot easier to write that reducer, it would perform a lot better and if you used memoized selectors (i.e. `reselect`) your app would perform A LOT better. Long story short: with redux try to keep the state of your store as normalized as possible. Now, I will go ahead and answer your question...

Comment: BTW, what's the action `type` of that action?

Comment: @Josep I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With es6 spread operator:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type !== actionTypes.UPDATE_CLICKED) return state;
  return {
     ...state,
     updates: {
       ...state.updates,
       html: {
         ...state.updates.html,
         items: state.updates.html.items.map((item, idx) => idx === action.id
           ? {...item, bought: item.bought}
           : item
         )
       }
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: Wait! I have not answered the second part of your question ;-)